# How to add admob ads to Xamarin IOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, ads

I am trying to add Admob Ads to Xamarin.IOS but i am unable to figure out way to achieve this goal.I have already searched internet but couldnt find the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Admob is available in Xamarin.iOS .

1.install the package [Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.AdMob](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/tree/master/Firebase.AdMob) from nuget.

2.Registring with AdMob

So, the first thing that you will need to do is actually register for AdMob. This is the same thing that I did in Android, but I created an iOS project. This will give you two important pieces of information, your “Application Code” and your “Ad Unit Id”. We will use these later, but simply go to: **https://apps.admob.com**, register for a new app, link to an app in Firebase, and you will be off running.

3.Add GoogleService-Info.plist

When you create the new app in Admob/Firebase there will be a Google Service config plist file that gets downloaded. Add this to the root of your iOS project and make sure that the Build Action is set to BundleResource. This is super important!

4.Update AppDelegate

```
MobileAds.Configure("Your Publishing App Id");
```

You can ask for more details about [Admob](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start) . And here is a [sample](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/355190) that you can refer.

Comment: I know uptil this point , please elaborate the next part of the code with some simple example

Comment: I have posted a sample link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/355190 here

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT there is no package Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.AdMob. That link is now a 404.