# Xamarin.ios native ads admob

Tags: xamarin.ios, admob, native-ads

I have been trying to figure out how to implement native google ads (admob) in my Xamarin.iOS app. **(not xamarin forms)**

I have googled like crazy but can't find any good examples.

Does anyone have any code that they could share?

This is my code so far, but the adloader.delegate is always null..

```
public partial class ExploreController : UIViewController
{
        readonly AdLoader adLoader;

     public ExploreController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
     {
            adLoader = new AdLoader(
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3986624511",
            this,
            new AdLoaderAdType[] { AdLoaderAdType.Native },
            new AdLoaderOptions[] { new AdLoaderOptions() });

            adLoader.Delegate = new MyAdLoaderDelegate();
            var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
    }
}


public class MyAdLoaderDelegate : NSObject, IUnifiedNativeAdLoaderDelegate
{

    public MyAdLoaderDelegate()
    {
    }

    public void DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd(AdLoader adLoader, NativeAd nativeAd)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DidReceiveUnifiedNativeAd");
    }
    public void DidFailToReceiveAd(AdLoader adLoader, NSError error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DidFailToReceiveAd");
        //base.DidFailToReceiveAd(adLoader, error);
    }

    public void DidFinishLoading(AdLoader adLoader)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DidFinishLoading");
        //base.DidFinishLoading(adLoader);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/marcojak/MTAdmob

Comment: Thank you! I saw this one but I need native ads and this seems to be for Xamarin Forms! @Jason

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add admob ads to Xamarin IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697807/how-to-add-admob-ads-to-xamarin-ios)

Comment: I saw that too, but the link to the sample returned 404 not found, and I really need some code to look at since i can't seem to get mine to work! @Jason

Comment: have you read this about how to do it https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-ios/

Comment: Yes, but didnt make me any wiser unfortunately! It doesn't seem to be many examples for native ads for Xamarin.ios @AdrainZhu-MSFT

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? It is the same for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for `Xamarin` iOS app with native `Storyboard`. This is **NOT** Xamarin Forms project.

1. Install NuGet package `Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds` (the latest)
2. You should have UIView for the banner, with all needed constrains (you edit Storyboard files in `XCode`):

[image: The C# code - in VS.]

3. Custom Class must be set to `GADBannerView`:

[image: Set Custom Class for the banner in XCode]

**NOTE:** You are using native name `GADBannerView` in Storyboard, while in C# you reference to the same class as just `BannerView`.

3. You also need an outlet so you can reference the banner instance from C# code:

[image: Outlet in XCode]

```
    [Outlet]
    [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
    BannerView bottomBanner { get; set; }
```

4. Now you should be able to reference your native AdMob banner from C# code. This is how you may load the ad:

   ```
    public void ShowBannerAd()
    {

        bottomBanner.RootViewController = this;

        bottomBanner.AdSize = AdSizeCons.Banner;

        bottomBanner.AdUnitId = "<YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID>";

        var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
        bottomBanner.LoadRequest(request);
    }
   ```

**The result:**

[image: AdMob ad in Simulator]